# Can't make sense of error in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I tried to compile code

```
module counter(
    input clk,
    input upSignal,
    input downSignal,
    output [7:0] count
   );
        always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
          if (upSignal)
              count <= count + 1;
          else if (downSignal)
              count <= count - 1;
        end
    endmodule
```

but I get the error

`Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at counter.v(7) near text "@";  expecting ".", or "("`

what does it mean?

Comment: Which software tool are you trying to compile this in? Some simulators default to Verilog-2001 syntax and need to be told to expect SystemVerilog...

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software. `always_ff` is a keyword in SystemVerilog, but not in Verilog-2001. Check the software's docs to see if you have to enable SystemVerilog support. If you're running it from the command line, it might be something like `-sv` or the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quartus does support some systemverilog. See this link for details >
[Quartus Help](http://quartushelp.altera.com/10.0/master.htm#mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_list_sys_vlog.htm?GSA_pos=2&WT.oss_r=1&WT.oss=systemverilog)

For quartus to automatically recognise that you are using system verilog, you need to call your file something.sv

So in this case, probably **counter.sv**

If your file is called **counter.v**, then you will get an error. I can confirm that is does indeed compile with Quartus II v10.0.

I would recommend changing your module output port to reg, Quartus didn't complain, but a simulator would.

```
output reg [7:0] count
```

Let us know how you get on.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think George is right (Hello George! Fancy seeing you here), the file is being interpreted as Verilog (not SystemVerilog), and so it doesn't understand always_ff.

On the type of the output value, I prefer the use of logic in SystemVerilog. Its effect is identical, but it gets away from the "Its declared 'reg' therefore it's a register' thinking that can catch people out.

Also, the reason you got that particular error message was that because it didn't know what always_ff was, it assumed it was the name of a module/interface/function. A module could have a port map that could start with a '.', and everything else would need an open bracket.

Answer (score 1):

One other problem with this code.

The count variable is assigned from a procedural block (always_ff) so the count variable needs to be declared as a variable type, typically logic type for this SystemVerilog code. The declaration should include: output **logic** [7:0] count